# Name for a part on stands/trainers

Tags: trainer, terminology

So I am building my own trainer/stand for my bike but I am hung up on one part. What is the official term for the part that attaches to the hex bolt on the rear wheel?

Comment: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cone-adjustment.html Maybe you see the part there?

Comment: I am looking for the part in the picture. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Tma-YImZmZSW42RU9wTFdDS1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you're in the US you could try getting these from a bike shop: 

http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=70062

Says it's a bolt on adapter but you may be able to use it or modify it for use.

Answer (score 3):

In the manuals/parts lists I have seen, Schwinn and Blackburn refer to the part that envelopes the ends of the axle or quick-release skewer as a "cone". Minoura refers to it as a "grommet" at the end of a "coupling".

I don't have a Cyclops manual handy. I also don't think there is an industry standard name for this part, as there is some variation between all manufacturers when it comes to the coupling/mounting mechanism of their trainers.

Comment: It's also not a part thats generally purchased outside of a trainer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect it to be called a cup, or a socket.

If you're making this yourself, consider a 6 sided socket and then weld a length of the beefiest threadded rod that fits through the square drive hole.   On the bike, use axle nuts instead of a QR and allow the minimum unsupported amount of rod.  You'll probably be using a burner back wheel and tyre anyway, not your good one.

To stop the socket undoing the axle nut, don't thread it through the stand, use a longish tube with thick washers and two nuts on either side.  Would be a bit fiddly to do up, but its going to be more stable.

Or simply run a longish bolt through the square socket hole and into the support.  It needs to be free to rotate a little but not to spin.

How do you intend on adding resistance to the system?